# details in an answer about $\Bbb Q[x]/\left<(x+1)^2\right> \cong \Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have  some  doubt  in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3350749/):

> Hint: In $\Bbb Q[x]/\left<(x+1)^2\right>$ there exists an element $a \neq 0$ for which $a^2 = 0$.

Can anybody explain /elaborate more about this answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He's remarking that in the factor ring, we have a non-trivial nilpotent element:

$$\overline w:=(x+1)+ \langle (x + 1)^2 \rangle\;,\;\;\overline w\neq 0\;,\;\;\text{but}\;\;\overline w^2=0$$

He then asks: is there such a (non-trivial nilpotent) element in $\;\Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q\;$ ? The answer is no, there is none...and thus both rings cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: okss  thanks u @DonAntonio sir   but one more  doubts is  that  If $\overline w^2=0$ then  from $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} =\overline w^2 \times \overline w^2=0$...

Comment: @jasmine I don't understand your doubt: $\;\overline w\;$ is an element of $\;\Bbb Q[x]/((x^2+1)^2)\;$ , not of $\;\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q\;$ , but if there was an isomorphism between the two rings then the image of $\;\overline w\;$ would also be non-trivial nilpotent in $\;\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q\;$ , which is impossible.

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm not sure I understand what you are writing in your answer. $(x^2+1)+\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is not an element in $\mathbb{Q}/\langle (x+1)^2 \rangle$

Comment: @G.Chiusole My bad, that was a typo. Just edited my answer and deleted the exponent. All the rest remains the same. BTW, it is still an element of the quotient, it is just not a nilpotent one...

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "$+ \mathbb{Q}[x]$". I think you want to write $\overline{w} := (x+1) + \langle (x+1)^2 \rangle$

Comment: Yes. Obvious mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I was remarking that in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle (x+1)^2 \rangle$ there exists a nilpotent element; that is $a:=\pi(x+1)$ where $\pi$ is the projection. The element $a$ is not zero, since it is not in $\langle (x+1)^2 \rangle$. However, its square is. Thus it is nilpotent of degree $2$.

In $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ there does not exist such an element. Pick some element $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$, which is non-zero, meaning $x \neq 0$ or $y \neq 0$. Then square it, and see that the result is non-zero again.

Hence the two rings cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: thanks  u  @G .Chiusole....Im  getting second point   but  not getting the  first point thta   How $a^2 = 0$  i mean  $\pi (x+1) = a  $ and $\pi(\pi(x+1)) = \pi(a) = a$

Comment: By $a^2$ I don't mean $\pi^2(x+1)$ but rather $(\pi(x+1))^2$. Recall here that $\pi$ is a homomorphism of rings. Hence $(\pi(x+1))^2 = \pi((x+1)^2) = 0$ since $(x+1)^2$ is in the kernel of $\pi$.

Comment: thanks u so  much  @G. chiusole   actually  it  take me a  3 hrs   to understand ur  answer

Comment: Glad to help. $~~~$